# How to check the number is among the sets of numbers in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a condition like:

```
if X is between (1 to 4) ----- value 0
if X is between(4 to 8) ----- value 1
if X is between(8 to 12) ----- value 2
if X is between(12 to 16) ----- value 3
```

and so on....

What is the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: You may need to care about if the value of int `X` is 0 or negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division in C# truncates, so if the number you are talking about is an integer and is assigned to the variable myInt, all you have to do is write an expression like this:

`(myInt -1) / 4`.

And if the number is a float, casting to int truncates, so just cast it like this:

`((int) myFloat - 1) /4`

Answer (score 4):

simply divide by 4:

```
int c = (int)(x - 1) / 4;
```

Comment: your ranges are not zero based (start with 1) so I had to take it off.

Comment: @Rehaan `x-1` will get you the desired output. Eg, if `x=4`, that will output 1, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
int x=5;
int num = (int)Math.Ceiling(x/4.0)-1;
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like

```
int result = (X - 1) / 4;
```